# Fatel error in magento when I click on attribute set

Tags: php, magento

This is the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Main/Abstract.php on line 217
```

Magento has fresh installation
Does anybody know how to resolve it?

Comment: You haven't installed any module yet?

Comment: no nothing i have added.its just a fresh installation and when i am clicking on add attribute set it is giving that error.rest works fine

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in magento. when I checked the folder found that there is an 1 file missing in folder location 'app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Edit' that is 'Js.php'. please check it will help